# Separation of table based on a trey component in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one table with two column:

```
+--------+----------------+
|position|Item            |
+--------+----------------+
|1       |FirstName       |
+--------+----------------+
|2       |john            |
+--------+----------------+
|3       |jack            |
+--------+----------------+
|4       |LastName        |
+--------+----------------+
|5       |Smith           |
+--------+----------------+
|6       |Warner          |
+--------+----------------+
|7       |DrivingLicenseNo|
+--------+----------------+
|8       |123             |
+--------+----------------+
|9       |456             |
+--------+----------------+
```

`First Name` has Changed from john to jack, 
`Last Name` has changed from smith to Warner and `DrivingLicenseNo` 
has changed from 123 to 456.

now I want to select from this table as the following form:

```
+----------------+-------+-------+
|FieldName       |OldData|NewData|
+----------------+-------+-------+
|FirstName       |john   |jack   |
+----------------+-------+-------+
|LastName        |Smith  |Warner |
+----------------+-------+-------+
|DrivingLicenseNo|123    |456    |
+----------------+-------+-------+
```

how I do that? Can any body help me regarding this....

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This Query

```
SELECT  T11.Name As FieldName ,
    T12.Name As OldName ,
    T13.Name As NewName
FROM    ( ( SELECT  T1.Id ,
                T1.Name
        FROM    dbo.T1
        WHERE   ( T1.Id % 3 = 1 )
      ) AS T11
      LEFT JOIN ( SELECT    T1.Id ,
                            T1.Name
                  FROM      dbo.T1
                  WHERE     ( T1.Id % 3 = 2 )
                ) AS T12 ON ( T11.Id + 1 = T12.id )
      LEFT JOIN ( SELECT    T1.Id ,
                            T1.Name
                  FROM      dbo.T1
                  WHERE     ( T1.Id % 3 = 0 )
                ) AS T13 ON ( T12.Id + 1 = T13.Id )
    )
```

And I have this table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T1](
[Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_T1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And I fill this table like this :

```
INSERT INTO dbo.T1
    ( Id, Name )
VALUES  ( 1,
      N'X'
      )

INSERT INTO dbo.T1
    ( Id, Name )
VALUES  ( 2,
      N'x1'
      )

INSERT INTO dbo.T1
    ( Id, Name )
VALUES  ( 3,
      N'x2'
      )

INSERT INTO dbo.T1
    ( Id, Name )
VALUES  ( 4,
      N'Y'
      )

INSERT INTO dbo.T1
    ( Id, Name )
VALUES  ( 5,
      N'y1'
      )

INSERT INTO dbo.T1
    ( Id, Name )
VALUES  ( 6,
      N'y2'
      )
```

[image]